# Not sure why this differential equation has infinitely many solutions at $y=1,-1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the differential equation I am given.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y(y^{2}-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

This is a seperable differential equation and I managed to figure out the solution to this equation is

$$y =±sec(x-c)$$

I also found out that the equation had singular solutions at $y = -1,1$. What I don't get is why the differential has infinitely many solutions at $y =1,-1$.

Wouldn't the solution at something like $y=1$ be

$$-arcsec(1)+x=c$$

Since only one value of $c$ works wouldn't that be unique?

Comment: My answer matches with the one in the back of the textbook. You can always try plugging the equation into the differential equation and verify whether it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$\pm\sec(x-c)$ is not a solution everywhere -- only the part between $c$ and $c+\frac\pi2$ where it moves *away* from $0$ is a solution. Between $c-\frac\pi2$ and $c$ the derivative is *minus* what the differential equation asks for.

A fuller solution would be the piecewise defined
$$ y(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{when } x \le c \\
 \sec(x-c) & \text{when } c < x < c+\frac\pi2
\end{cases} $$

If your boundary condition is $y(0)=1$, then each of the infinitely many combinations of choices of $c\ge 0$ will yield a solution.

Comment: I was wondering how did you get the solution y(x) = 1 when x =< c?

Comment: @user262291: It is a solution because then $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ which also happens to be the value of $y\sqrt{y^2-1}$ when $y=1$.